# SQL: where data doesn't match using JOIN, I want it to return values from different column

Tags: sql, mysql, join, null, match

I have 2 tables that I join using LEFT JOIN, i.e. I take Name from table A and match it to Name from table B. There are some records that do not match and return null values due to it being formatted differently.

Now what I want to do is wherever it isn't matching, I want to extract the first word in Names from table A and search for it in names in Table B and return those values.

Could someone please help me achieve this? I am giving example below:

Table A:

| Names |
| --- |
| Allianz games |
| Beta Test |
| Car Company |

Table B:

| Names | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Allianz games ltd | 1 |
| Beta Test | 2 |
| Car Company | 3 |

Output I am getting using LEFT JOIN:

| A.Names | B.Names | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allianz games | Null | Null |
| Beta Test | Beta Test | 2 |
| Car Company | Car Company | 3 |

Output I require:

| A.Names | B.Names | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allianz games | Allianz games ltd | 1 |
| Beta Test | Beta Test | 2 |
| Car Company | Car Company | 3 |

Comment: Please edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: @SelVazi I just added some examples

Answer (score 0):

You could try two joins - first using an exact match, the second using a 'LIKE' match but only if there isn't an exact match:

```
SELECT
  a.Names AS 'A.Names',
  IFNULL(b_exact.Names, b_approx.Names) AS 'B.Names',
  IF(b_exact.Names IS NULL, b_approx.Type, b_exact.Type) AS 'Type'
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b_exact ON
  a.Names = b_exact.Names
LEFT JOIN table_b b_approx ON
  (b_exact.Names IS NULL AND b_approx.Names LIKE CONCAT(a.Names, '%'))
```

You'll need to take care with this, however, because there could potentially be multiple matches in Table B.

Answer (score 0):

So, you already have a

```
SELECT A.Names, B.Names, B.`Type`
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.Names = B.Names
```

and you successfully find exact matches. You, however want to display results if the second table contains the first. You can get all records like this:

```
SELECT A.Names, B.Names, B.`Type`
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.Names = B.Names OR B.Names LIKE CONCAT('%', A.Names, '%')
```

but this will provide all results and if you want a single result for each A, then you can group by and aggregate, like this:

```
SELECT A.Names,
       CASE
           WHEN MAX(A.Names = B.Names) > 0 THEN A.Names
           ELSE MIN(B.Names)
       END AS Names
       MAX(B.`Type`)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.Names = B.Names OR B.Names LIKE CONCAT('%', A.Names, '%')
GROUP BY A.Names
```

Finally, if you want to include cases where A.Names contains B.Names, then you can change your join condition to

```
ON A.Names = B.Names OR B.Names LIKE CONCAT('%', A.Names, '%') OR A.Names LIKE CONCAT('%', B.Names, '%')
```